# A tool to create full SQL-Sever database backup on a shared hosting?

Tags: sql-server, hosting, backup

I have a website on a shared hosting. I want to do a full backup of a Sql-Server 2005 database. I can connect to db using server management studio but I cannot do full backup because I cannot reach any filesystem (due to hosting limitations). 
Can anybody help?

Comment: If you don't have **any** file-system permissions, and your hosting provider isn't willing to open those up at least a tiny bit, then I really don't see how you can achieve this, sorry....

Comment: I can extract DB schema and content of all tables to sql script using EMS SQL Manager. It's acceptable for a small database but rather too heavy for something larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should talk to your hosting and see what they recommend to make full backup, meanwhile you can use Import/Export Data to transfer data to a local Database.

**Edit:**
After searching on this issue I found the following article:
[automatically taking backup of database on shared hosting having SQL Server 2005 express on my machine ? Plz guide](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/6528ebc3-fd5a-4677-b6d5-421451f7716b)

Comment: Hosting support can do the backup when I create a ticket and wait a day for processing it. I'd like to do it on my own.